# When I run the command "pub global activate stagehand" ,I got following error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-pub, dart-html

pub : The term 'pub' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

when I run flutter doctor I got everything correct.

Comment: tried `flutter pub global activate stagehand`?

Comment: now i tried and it works...thanks pskink